# Removing a class from a child component inluded via transclusion

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 5.0 to create a library of components based on Semantic UI. I'm currently stuck trying to work out how to remove a class from child component that is included in it's parent via transclusion and may, in fact, not be there at all.

The issue stems from the way Semantic UI creates labeled icon buttons. A normal icon button would have the following HTML:

```
<div class="ui icon button" tabindex="0"><i class="flag icon"></i> Flag</div>
```

In my library, this is made using:

```
<div sui-button icon="flag">Flag</div>
```

However, a labeled icon button is normally:

```
<div class="ui labeled button" tabindex="0">
  <div class="ui button"><i class="flag icon"></i> Flag<div>
  <a class="ui basic label">Test</a>
</div>
```

If I was to create this through my library, the child button would also have the "icon" class which causes the CSS to break.

```
<div sui-button class="labeled">
  <div sui-button icon="flag">Flag</div>
  <a sui-label class="basic">Test</a>
</div>
```

In my component, I have tried the following as a test to check for the child button inside it's parent:

```
export class SemanticButtonComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewComponent {
  @Input('icon') icon: string = "";
  @Input('flag') flag: string = "";
  @ViewChild(SemanticButtonComponent) childButton: SemanticButtonComponent;

  constructor(private el:ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if ("" !== this.icon || "" !== this.flag) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'icon')
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.childButton);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this just outputs "undefined" for both instances. Is it not finding it because the component is transcluded? Is there any way I could reference the child button without it being included in the template?